# Android - Invariant failed: Browser history needs a DOM

Tags: react-router-dom

I fetch a list of articles from my site backend (nodejs) and print it in the react demo app.

The app works correctly from the Web. When I try to start it in Android I get the following error:

```
Invariant failed: Browser history needs a DOM
```

I think the problem is here:

```
import {BrowserRouter, Router, Link, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
...
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
     <Route path="/detail/:id" component={RouterDetail}/>
     <Route exact={true} path="/home" render={() => content}/>
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

I have read everything on the web about this error but I have not been able to understand the problem.
I found a lot about react server side.

But my case is different, i use react only as a frontend.

I also tried the following change, from web works, on android I encounter the same problem:

```
import { Router } from "react-router";
import {Link, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
...
const history = createBrowserHistory();
...
<Router history={history}>
  <Route path="/detail/:id" component={RouterDetail}/>
  <Route exact={true} path="/home" render={() => props.content}/>
</Router>
```